# R equivalent of MATLAB's fmincon for constrained optimization?

Tags: r, matlab, mathematical-optimization

Is there an equivalent to the MATLAB function [fmincon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fmincon.html)() which finds the minimum of a constrained non-linear function (with linear equality AND inequality constraints) in R?

I can rule out constrOptim (doesn't support equality constraints) and quadprog (only quadratic functions) which are listed on the R [Optimization task](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package [`nloptr`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/) is an R interface to [NLopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt), a library for nonlinear optimization with algorithms for unconstrained optimization, bound-constrained optimization, and general nonlinear inequality/equality constraints.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a package called [pracma](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/pracma/html) which includes [fmincon()](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/pracma/html/fmincon.html) function similar to Matlab version.